# eclipse doesn't recognize resources in bin folder (by relative filepath)

Tags: java, eclipse

This is driving me crazy. I've spent hours googling this and cannot find a single other case of someone with this problem. I have put all my needed images for my program into the src folder, but when I run the program it does not draw the images. I check the bin folder, and they HAVE been properly copied. Even with all of the resources in the bin folder, eclipse doesn't recognize them when I use the relative filepath. If I open a command prompt and cd to the bin folder and run it, all of the images are drawn, with no changes to the code. How can I get eclipse to use the images by relative filepath??

Comment: please try by copying images to the root folder in projects lets know if you face any issues..

Comment: Thank you Thanga! I don't know why I didn't think of this... but is there by chance a way to change where eclipse looks for images when you use the relative filepath?

Comment: i think so we dont wanna specify any relative in eclipse when its in the project folder .. just use the file name alone..  is it working now ? @tyler

Comment: @Thanga yeah its working now. I put the images in the project folder instead of the bin/ folder. But I was wanting to know if I could change it to were eclipse would use the images in the bin folder instead of the project folder.

Comment: i have added the answer below find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Copy images` to the `root folder` in to the `project` it should work for you, by default the `eclipse` will read the `file` within the `project` by simply specifying its name and consider it as relative path . `Bin` folder normally used to store all the `class files` after compilation of java file  in eclipse , this should be the reason for avoiding ,you can add the relative path of the file in to source code with its seperate folers.

Correct me if 'm worng

Answer (score 0):

When you try to access a file using `new File("some/relative/path")`, the path is always relative to the location the Java application was started from. When you are unsure which location this is, you can find out by printing `new File(".").getAbsolutePath()`. In case of Eclipse, this will be the Project folder.

If you want to access files in the source folders of your application, you should rather use `class.getResource("path")` or `class.getResourceAsStream("path")`. Here, path can be either a relative path (relative to the package of the `class`) or an absolute path (absolute w.r.t. the class path).

So if you have a package `foo` and in this package a java file `Bar.java` and an image `blub.gif`, you can get the image by using either `Bar.class.getResource("blub.gif")` or `Bar.class.getResource("/foo/blub.gif")` -- note the leading `/`.

Other than using `new File(...)`, this will also work then the classes and resources are packaged in a Jar.